# SSIS delete folders named with a date

Tags: sql-server, ssis

My process ceates automatically some new folders named with a date i.e (09-01-2011) in a directory (Archive)
How can I check the date of the folder in the directory and delete those older than a certain date?

Thanks

Comment: Just to be clear, it's the folder's label that is the signal for deletion, not the actual folder create date. Thus, I make a folder today but call it 2009-01-01, the package should delete it. Can we assume the contents of the folder are empty?

Comment: yes, it's the folder's label which contains the date. The folders won't be empty because they contain archive files, but I want to delete all folders older than current date -30 for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use for_each_folder_enumeration technology from here:
   http://microsoft-ssis.blogspot.com/2011/01/foreach-folder-enumerator.html
2. Analyze folder name using Script component
3. Check if folder is empty using Microsoft suggestion: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/a3240e00-ac9d-4082-b1e4-72bd7f695524/
4. Move folder using File System Task (Copy directory)